# Sporadic AWS RDS postgres Connection timeout and EOF detected from t2.xlarge

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, sqlalchemy, tornado

I'm running a `db.m5.xlarge` postgres 10.6 db on AWS RDS. 2 weeks ago, we started getting sporadic `(psycopg2.DatabaseError) SSL SYSCALL error: Connection timed out` and `(psycopg2.OperationalError) SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected`.

These errors all come from Docker containers that are running on a `t2.xlarge` instance. The `t2.xlarge` is running 20 Docker containers, each container us running a simple Python Tornado API.

When we get these errors, it's not all containers on the host that get the error, it's random ones. After the errors, and we rollback the session (we're using sqlalchemy), the errors go away.

We've tried upgrading our DB, running fewer containers on the `t2.xlarge`, upgrading to an `m5.xlarge` but nothing is working.

Our DB load looks normal.

We've been trying a bunch of things but are running out of ideas. Could this be something to do with AWS throttling our `t2.xlarge` or `m5.xlarge` network usage?

The `t2.xlarge` has ~200-250K network in/out, and ~500-600 packets in/out consistently. CPU usage on these instances is ~0.3.

**edit**

the postgres error logs are showing tons of logs like this

```
unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction
could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
```

So it looks like it's something to do with the Tornado server's we're running that are using sqlalchemy to talk to the db. Any tips/advice on what to look for/debug from here with sqlalchemy/tornado would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you connect to your db using `psql` CLI?

Comment: Yeah -- the tornado API communicates with the DB no problem and then sporadically we see these errors, then after a few mins the connection starts to work again

Comment: Seems like there is some uncaught exception that's crashing the tornado server and the connection to the db doesn't get closed properly. At least, according to this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgres-logs-errors#log-unexpected-eof-on-client-connection. Turn on tornado logging to find out more about the errors on the client side.

Comment: Amazon's `t`-series instances are subject to some pretty severe CPU throttling if they're not in "unlimited" mode; I've seen this cause timeouts like this. As a general rule you can have trouble if CPU utilization averages over 25% for a 24-hour period. That's more likely to be your problem than the network, I think.

Comment: I just checked and our average CPU-util for the past 24 hour period averages around 3-4%. We're also seeing really slow pushes to SQS (sporadically) from the same instances, which makes me thinks its got to be something network related?

Comment: any clue on this issue?